# How to get current browser url using mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want current browser URL (ex : http://localhost:1495/Global/General/SectionSetting)
i have tried below code but i am getting API URL (ex : http://localhost:1495/api/Apiname/Functionname)

```
string sPagePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

 String baseUrl = Path.GetDirectoryName(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need the exact url, including query string, of this request? Or do you want to generate an absolute url to a specific page / controller?

Comment: "http://localhost:1495/api/Apiname/Functionname" has no "browser" associated with it... Why one calling such method would even use a browser? So much easier to use HttpClient (in C#) or even curl... You may want to [edit] the question to clarify your scenario...

Answer (score 0):

In client and server disconnected architecture in asp.net Web API 2 I was used `HttpContext.Header.Referrer` to get the client host information.  This will just provide you the base absolute URL only. The browser relative path is not included on it.

From you question I can understand that you need the browser address on ajax request. One possible solution is to send the browser current url into api with ajax request. You can get the browser full url using javascript `location`. For example

`var absolutePath = window.location;`

As I don't see your code, I just try to share my thoughts. Let's see if it's helpful for you. You can share your code to get better suggestions or solutions.